# Setting view contraints programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to set a view constraint on the bottom of `self.view` programmatically in viewDidLoad. I want the view to end 80px above the bottom of the screen.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What kind of constraint? What have you tried? Need a bit more information than this... look into NSLayoutConstraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looking at the AutoLayout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html), it looks like what you could do is something like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *myNewConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view.window
                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-80.0];
```

and once you have that constraint created, you need to *install* it into the view... using something like:

```
[self.view addConstraint:myNewConstraint];
```

Now I've never done this, so the values might be a bit off.  But hopefully this sends you down the right path!

Comment: Thanks. I put this in viewDidLoad in a class that is a UIViewController and I get the error that no property "window" is found

Comment: Whoops, should be "self.view.window". B.T.W., it sounds like what you *really* need to be doing here is just setting the constraint in your storyboard or XIB file, if you have one.